# This new puzzle type needs a name {6}

Tags: logical-deduction, word, enigmatic-puzzle, grid-deduction, reverse-puzzling

I believe I have invented** a new type of puzzle...

> **What is its name?**

[image]

Begin by solving the Fillomino puzzle:

> **Rules of Fillomino** (adapted from [Nikoli](http://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/fillomino.html))
>
> - Fill in all empty cells with numbers under the following rules.
> - Numbers should be grouped together into 'blocks' of orthogonally connected cells in which each cell contains the same number.
> - The total number of cells making up each 'block' equals the value they all share (e.g. a block of two 2's, three 3's, etc.).
> - Different 'blocks' of the same size and value cannot border each other, horizontally or vertically (but may touch at a corner).

Then apply some [grid-deduction-deduction](/questions/tagged/grid-deduction-deduction) (!) and discover its name! Answers which explain the deduction process are appreciated even more - thanks!

<sub>** *NB After creating this puzzle, I realised that [@Reinier](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/47439/reinier) has created something with similar inspiration before, but I believe our two puzzles are sufficiently different... Try to resist peeking at [their puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87308/slitherlink-fillomino-hybrid) before solving this one! :)*</sub>

---

<sup>*Other puzzles in the 'This new puzzle type needs a name' theme: [01](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92013/this-new-puzzle-type-needs-a-name), [02](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92586/another-new-puzzle-type-needs-a-name), [03](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92922/this-new-puzzle-type-needs-a-name-3), [04](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/93372/this-new-puzzle-type-needs-a-name-4), [05](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/93830/this-new-puzzle-type-needs-a-name-5)*</sup>

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First, the Fillomino should be solved:

> [image]

Then,

> all of the blue shaded cells are numbers from 1-3. This can be solved as a Slitherlink:
>
>  [image]

And finally:

> The letters the loop passes over (clockwise from the top left)...
>  [image]
>  ...spell FILLERLINK.

Comment: Now *that* was a speedy solve! 44 minutes after posting?? (descending whistle...) Well done, and a checkmark for you!

Comment: I don't understand your step 2

Comment: @StephenR In the original puzzle, some cells are shaded blue. Those numbers only can be copied to a new grid, and then solved as a Slitherlink.